# PHP Kohana. Htaccess seems to be preventing access to subfolder.

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kohana

I am having an issue with a site in that it seems like my htaccess file (situated in web root) is preventing access to any php files in subdirectories. I've tested this by creating a new test folder and adding a php file to it which does a simple echo. I always get a 500 error.

This issue only recently started happening. The htaccess rules I have are the same as many other sites I run on my own server, however this one site is hosted by a different company. Does anyone know why this could be happening? Could a change on the server have caused this possibly?

This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>

# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/kohana/, use /kohana/
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteCond $1 ^(app_admin|app_public|system)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Do not enable rewriting for other files that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: What does your Apache error log say? If you get a 500 error, Apache always logs a message telling you what the problem was...

Comment: @Dave - I get `pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable` - however, htaccess is readable and executable as it has 755 permissions.

Comment: Check the codepage of the file, your editor may have converted it to some kind of multibyte charset that Apache doesn't like? That error indicates that permissions are not valid, so triple check the permissions, maybe `chown`/`chgrp` it to the web server user, and check the permissions of the directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/61726/permission-denied-home-htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htaccess-file) from ServerFault. It's definitely a permissions issue. Per that discussion, make sure the parent folders also have the proper permissions or Apache can't descend into the folder with the .htaccess file to read it.

Comment: Spot on. Not sure how it happened exactly but the permissions were screwed on the parent folders. Thanks